# How to string.Join result of GetHostAddresses call?

Tags: c#, messagebox

Im tring to join the string to display in the messagebox, but not sure why I get error at this line:

```
IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(he.HostName);
var addr = string.Join(",",ips); // the error display invalid argument.
MessageBox.Show(addr);
```

I know this sound basic. But I'm new in this, can someone help me?

Error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'string.Join(string, params object[])' and 'string.Join(string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'

Comment: Please check if you are ok with my edit - removed code unrelated to the problem (some `for` loop), changed title to reflect the issue  and added  error message that you should be getting... Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 5):

Use `ToList` method or an explicit cast:

```
 string.Join(",", (IEnumerable<IPAddress>)ips);
```

Or specify the generic argument explicitly:

```
string.Join<IPAddress>(",", ips);
```

The compiler can't decide which overload it should choose from one of these: `string.Join(string, params object[])` or `string.Join(string,IEnumerable<IPAdress>)` so you need to tell the compiler which method do you want to call explicitly.Also it seems you don't need that `foreach` loop.

Comment: i try this code but i get this error "cannot convert from'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Net.IPAddress>' to 'string[]'" any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just "join" a list of objects and have it do something meaningful.. unless perhaps that class overrides `ToString()`.

Try selecting the field you want to display:

```
var addr = string.Join(",", ips.Select(x => x.SomeFieldToDisplay));
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it doesn't seem like you need the for-loop. The `string.Join` method will do that work for you.

Second, `string.Join`'s second argument should (typically) be an `IEnumerable<string>` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), but you tried passing it an `IEnumerable<IPAddress>`. You can leave your `ips` as a regular array, but you should help the `Join` function out and convert each `IPAddress` to whatever string representation you'd like, such as the standard IP address notation:

```
var addr = string.Join(",", ips.Select(ip => ip.ToString()).ToArray());
```

The `.ToArray()` may or may not be required depending on which version of the .NET framework you're using.

Comment: both `ToString` and `ToArray` are _redundant_ Join method calls ToString on each object and there is an overload of `string.Join` takes an `IEnumerable<T>`...

Comment: I try this code, but got this error "system.array does not contain defination for select" any idea?

Comment: @Selman22: Fair enough, but they are only redundant if you're using .NET 4+. These magical `string.Join` overloads did not exist before then.

Comment: @Ren: What version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: @Ren: Make sure you have a `using System.Linq;` statement at the top.

Comment: sorry, but why i cant add the system.Linq namespace?

Comment: Make sure you have a reference to `System.Core` in your project.